# SAS forward looking Moving standard deviation

Tags: sas

Hi does anyone know how to calculate the standard deviation over the next four quarters for each quarter? Thanks :)

My attempt is below: 
date1 is the sas date for the quarter in a year

```
  Proc sql ; create table th.totalroll as 
 Select distinct permco, date1 , 
 (select  std(adjret) from th.returns1 where  qtr between   
  intnx('quarter',qtr(date),0)  and intnx('quarter', qtr(date),+3)) as       
    TOTALroll From th.returns1 group by permco ,date1;
   QUIT;
```

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS licenced?  If so then PROC EXPAND can calculate this for you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how close you are because I'm not entirely certain what your data looks like, but here's an example assuming you have more than one date in each quarter. Create sample data:

```
data have;
  format date date9.;
  do m = 1 to 128;
    date = intnx('month','01JAN2008'd,m-1);
    amount = round(ranuni(date)*10);
    output;
  end;
  drop m;
run;
```

Using proc sql, create `quarter` variable (you might already have this variable?) and group by this variable. Use a `having` clause to restrict results to the first date of each quarter.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
  yyq(year(t1.date),qtr(t1.date)) as quarter format=yyq.,
  (select std(t2.amount)
   from have t2
   where t2.date >= yyq(year(t1.date),qtr(t1.date))
     and t2.date < intnx('quarter',yyq(year(t1.date),qtr(t1.date)),4)) as stddev
from
  have t1
group by
  calculated quarter
having
  t1.date = min(t1.date)
;
quit;
```

You should be able to adapt this to work for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proc expand if your dataset is already in quarterly. So something like this:

```
proc expand data=th.returns1 
           out=th.totalroll
           from=quarter
           to=quarter;
  by permco date1;         
  id date;
  convert adjret=TOTALroll /  transformout=( MOVSTD 4 );
run;
```

Don't forget to sort you data first. And MOVSTD gives you backward moving standard deviation. You may need to shift the output stream back by 4 quarters if you want the forward moving STD.

Transformation Operations for proc expand: 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect026.htm